# How can I override a source script that has a different path location every page reload on a website with chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to override a javascript source document on a website using chrome dev tools. However, whenever I reload the page, the path to the source document also changes (eg. from `example.com/path/abc123/to/file.js` to `example.com/path/xyz456/to/file.js`), causing my changes to not take effect. Is it possible to override this using some form of text matching or some other method?